# Как можно вывести товары из 2 инфоблоков в Битрикс?

Tags: битрикс

Как можно вывести товар из 2 инфоблоков? 
У меня в цикле собираются id нужных товаров (2 разных инфоблока)

```
$recom[] = "189065";
$recom[] = "188039";
$recom[] = "187960";
$recom[] = "188811";
$recom[] = "85757";

$arrFilter = Array(
    "ID"=>$recom,
    "IBLOCK_ID"=>array(22,29)
);
```

и через bitrix:catalog.section пытаюсь вывести. Но компонент выводит товары только из одного инфоблока.

Comment: а для чего в $arrFilter присутствует фильтр по ID элементов?

Comment: @zagazat хочу вывести именно эти пять товаров, но они находятся в разных инфоблоках.